# Simplifying equations in Sympy using inequalities

Tags: sympy, reduce, inequality

I am trying in Sympy to use a standard engineering method of simplifying an equation, where you know one variable is much larger or smaller than another. For instance, given the equation

`C1*R2*s+C1*R2+R1+R2`

and knowing that

`R1 >> R2`

the equation can be simplified to

`C1*R2*s+C1*R2+R1`.

What you'd normally do by hand is divide by R1, giving

`C1*R2*s/R1+C1*R2/R1+1+R2/R1`

then anyplace you see R2/R1 *by itself* you can set it to zero and then multiply by R1. I've not been able to figure how this would be done in Sympy. Obviously it's easy to do the division step, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do the search and replace step- just using subs gives you

`R1`

which isn't the right answer. factor, expand, collect, don't seem to get me anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`replace`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.replace) instead of `subs` works here.

```
C1, C2, R1, R2 = sp.symbols('C1, C2, R1, R2', real = True)
s = sp.symbols('s')

expr = C1*R2*s+C1*R2+R1+R2
print('original expression:', expr)

expr_approx = (R1 * ((expr/R1).expand().replace(R2/R1,0))).simplify()
print('approximate expression:', expr_approx)
```

> ```
> original expression: C1*R2*s + C1*R2 + R1 + R2
> approximate expression: C1*R2*s + C1*R2 + R1
> ```

Comment: I didn't choose my example well enough.

Comment: Suppose it was `C1*R1*s + R1*Re + R2*Re`. You'll end up with the original equation because `(expr/R1).expand()` results in `C1*s+Re+R2*Re/R1`, and `replace(R2/R1,0)` doesn't recognize `R2*Re/R1`

Comment: I can almost get it to work using `replace` wildcards except for each term has a 1.0 in front of it (I've been omitting those for clarity) and `replace` then results in everything being 0- I don't know how to get rid of those. So I'm really trying to simplify something like `1.0*C1*R1*s+1.0*R1*Re+1.0*R2*Re`. Dividing by 1.0 doesn't work :(

Comment: @TomSpargo Use `sympy.nsimplify(1.0*C1*R1*s+1.0*R1*Re+1.0*R2*Re)` to get rid of `1.0`. Maybe someone else has a better overall solution.

Comment: I've been trying to use wildcards to make replace work, I think once I understand them this is the way to do it.